# Which were the most important ghettos during Holocaust?

Tags: holocaust

I have to make a project about ghettos during Holocaust and I was thinking of focusing in some ghettos as there are so many in Wikipedia at this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nazi-era_ghettos

There is some information also at http://www.holocaustresearchproject.org/ghettos/ where there are some ghettos not mentioned in wikipedia.

Can you tell me the names of the most important of these?

Can you give a list of the destruction ghettos?
Thank you

Comment: Most important to whom?

Comment: @Mark C. Wallance That are considered generally more important

Comment: I think the residents of each ghetto would consider their own the most important. I don't know  of an objective standard for "importance" of a ghetto.  Size? Proximity? Effectiveness of isolation? cost of enforcement? Personally I can't distinguish between an important ghetto and an unimportant ghetto.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace  Can you tell me are all those ghettos destruction ghettos?

Comment: The source to which you link clarifies that "In short, despite Heydrich’s instructions, there was no consistently discernible pattern to ghettoisation, and policy decisions were frequently taken at a local level." I think most of your answers are in that source.

Comment: On the other hand, if you're asking about Nazi ghettos, then your source provides the answer, "he ghettos of the Holocaust were described by one inmate as “a prison without a roof.” 

But they were much worse than that. A prison sentence offered at least the prospect of survival. For those interned in the ghettos, there was no such prospect. Slow and lingering, or swift and brutal, their fate was likely to be the same."  Extermination through isolation.

Comment: @TylerDurden I am just looking for some help to find sources and I'm not asking anyone select or give the complete work done... SO next time read the question twice, if you don't get it the first time.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace So is there any link where I can find all the complete list of Extermination ghettos? I don't know how to select between all those ghettos. In the second link the ghettos are those on the left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Tyler pointed out in his comment, we are not going to do your homework for you. I'm going to ask some questions. It is important that you answer them for **yourself**. Giving the answers to us is secondary.

*What is the audience supposed to take from your project? (I'm assuming that there will be some sort of presentation.)*

- Ghettos existed long before the Holocaust. Nazis made use of pre-existing ethnic neighbourhoods for their purposes. There is a difference between a street where the Jews live and a closed ghetto.
- The ghetto system was part of the Nazi genocide. People were held in ghettos prior to their [deportation to camps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grossaktion_Warsaw_%281942%29) and they were killed *in* the ghettos, through systematic starvation and other means.
- The ghetto system held their inmates in locations where the labor force could be exploited.
- The ghettos had some degree of [self-organization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_Ghetto_Police). This led to collaboration but also to [organized resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warsaw_Ghetto_Uprising).

*What should be mentioned, even if the audience probably won't remember the details?*

- A map with dots for each ghetto.
- Different kinds of ghetto. Open, closed, extermination.
- Numbers. Total inmates, total deaths in ghettos, the size of the largest ghettos.
- The timeline how they fit into the [Endlösung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Solution) plans.

*What skills are you supposed to learn and show with your project?*

- Research. You want to show to your teachers that you can take a topic where you have no knowledge and find the relevant information from books, the internet, etc.
- Presentation. You want to show your teachers that you can present your results in a clear, concise manner.

Depending on **your** time for the preparation and for the presentation, you might not be able to cover all the bullet points, or you might add some more. If you have lots of time, you might ask a Jewish congregation in your neighbourhood if there are ghetto survivors still alive, but before you do that you should talk to your teachers.

**TL;DR** Warsaw. It was large, it shows deportation to and from ghettos, it fought.

Comment: Can you tell me where an i find a list of Extermination ghettos? Because my teacher told me to be based on those

Comment: Take a look at the German wikipedia page; "vor Ort ermordet" means "murdered at the site": https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Ghettos_in_der_Zeit_des_Nationalsozialismus